# Regex : starting group leading to space match

Tags: javascript, regex

```
([^("|'|>)])((http(s)?:\/\/|www\.)[A-Z0-9._%+\-\/]*)(?!["|'])
```

I am using the above on the following text:

```
this is the world truning at the ground level https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange this is the world truning at the ground level
this is the world truning at the ground levelthis is the world truning at the ground levelthis is the world truning at the ground levelthis is the world truning at the ground levelthis is the world truning at the ground levelthis is the world truning at the ground levelthis is the world truning at the ground levelthis is the world truning at the ground levelthis is the world truning at the ground levelthis is the world truning at the ground levelthis is the world truning at the ground level http://desktop.com
http://desktop.com http://desktop.com ahsdjhaldhjashdk
```

If I use this regex on the passage above, I get all the links but with a preceeding space. I need a REGEX that checks the condition that I have but select the preceeding space.

I have the preceding check of `([^("|'|>)])` as I need that if I the following text of:

```
<a href="http://desktop.com/" target="_blank" data-mce-href="http://desktop.com">http://desktop.com</a>
```

Then none of the URLS in this get selected.

Comment: What if you replace your `([^("|'|>)])` with `(\b)`

Comment: No, you do not need `([^("|'|>)])`, you need to parse the anchor node value from HTML with DOM. Then, you won't have this trouble. Just collect all text nodes, and then collect the links if you do not want URLs from inside tags (e.g. attributes).

Comment: However, I guess you are looking for [this](https://jsfiddle.net/938vLpmp/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually i after identifying the URLS, i need to convert them into a link.

Comment: @Adam : \b wasnnt working .. can you please provide the regex?

Comment: See [Auto-link URL with javascript Regex (no libraries)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747733/auto-link-url-with-javascript-regex/29747837#29747837). Please let me know if that works for you. Besides, you might want to check [3rd party libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/(?!(?:p|pre)>))((https?:)\/\/[a-z0-9&#=.\/\-?_]+)/gi;
```

Worked. This can be found in [a post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747733/auto-link-url-with-javascript-regex/29747837#29747837).